# Getting client ID using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Im trying to validate a textbox by getting the client ID using the below and then testing its value
The textbox is in a ModalPopupExtender which is in a updatepanel
However JQuery doesnt seem to be returning anything, the control is always NULL
This textbox is inside a gridview

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quick Donate">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnQuickDonate" runat="server"
                                        CommandName="Insert"
                                        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                                        OnClick="btnQuickDonate"
                                        Text="Quick Donate" />
                                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalDonationPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnQuickDonate" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
                                        Enter Donation Amount<br />
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnOnePound" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="1" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnFivePound" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="5" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnTenPound" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="10" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnFifteenPound" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="15" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnTwentyPounds" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="20" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnTwentyFivePounds" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="25" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnThirtyPounds" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="30" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnFiftyPounds" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClick="btnQuickDonate" Text="50" />

                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <%--  --%>
                                        </table>
                                        <br />

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFreeDonationAmount" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  ></asp:TextBox>
                                        **<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" Text="OK" OnClientClick="return valtxtBoxFreeDonation();" OnClick="btnQuickDonate"></asp:Button>**
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />

                                    </asp:Panel>
```

Javascript below I have also tried $('#txtFreeDonationAmount') with no joy...

```
function valtxtBoxFreeDonation() {
    var txtDonation = $('#<%=txtFreeDonationAmount.ClientID %>');

     if (txtDonation.val().length < 0) {
        // do something
        apprise("Please Enter a Donation Amount before click okay");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the resulting HTML and see if the ID property is present there

Comment: <input type="submit" name="GridView1$ctl03$btnOK" value="OK" onclick="return valtxtBoxFreeDonation();" id="GridView1_btnOK_1" tabindex="-1">  ---- this is the code that is the html code that is returned in the debugger looks like the ID has changed quite significantly

Comment: <input name="GridView1$ctl02$txtFreeDonationAmount" type="text" id="GridView1_txtFreeDonationAmount_0" commandargument="0">  --- this is the correct output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bold solution is jsut to take this id 'GridView1_btnOK_1` and use it in your JS.

```
$('#GridView1_txtFreeDonationAmount_0')
```

And as mentiones about the `$('#<%=txtFreeDonationAmount.ClientID %>')` will work only if your JS is in the same `.aspx` file.

Answer (score 10):

This code:

```
var txtDonation = $('#<%=txtFreeDonationAmount.ClientID %>');
```

will work properly only when JavaScript is inside `.aspx` file.